# How to convert ARGB Hex string to image

Tags: python

I have a ARGB hexstring:

```
"FFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFFFFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFA30000FFFFFFFF".
```

How to convert it to an image?

I have try using python to convert but it produces a invalid image.

```
text = "FFFFFFFFFFA30000......" #hex code
integers = []

while text:
    value = int(text[:2], 16)
    integers.append(value)
    text = text[2:]

data = bytearray(integers)    
    
with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    print(fh.write(data))
```

Comment: Why are you writing random data to a `jpg`? Image formats use compression and various headers and footers and metadata. `.bmp` is a simpler format and you can write it by hand but still you need to include the magic number and header.

Comment: you write only `raw data` (pixels) - but real file `jpg`/`png`/`gif`/`tiff`.etc, needs something more - magic number, headers, information about colors, information about used compression, and compressed data (not raw data). You would have to use module `PIL` or `cv2` to write it correctly,. ie. `cv2.imdecode()`,`cv2.imencode()`.

Comment: how did you get this string? If you used some module to generate this string then you should try use the same module to convert it to correct file.